# \begin{doublespacing} Versus \begin{spacing}{2.0}

Tags: spacing, setspace

The following `\begin{doublespacing}` only affects `FIRST`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{doublespacing}
FIRST

SECOND

\end{doublespacing}
THIRD

FOURTH
\end{document}
```

In contrast, `\begin{spacing}{2.0}` affects both `FIRST` and `SECOND`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{2.0}
FIRST

SECOND

\end{spacing}
THIRD

FOURTH
\end{document}
```

Why are they different?

Comment: `\doublespacing` as defined by `\usepackage{setspace}` is not an environment. It is a switch. (It is a quirk of LaTeX that you can use normal commands also as environments.) In particular `\end{doublespacing}` only closes a group and does nothing else. (In partcular this requires the slightly unnatural empty line/`\par` before `\end{doublespacing}`). `\begin{spacing}{2.0}...\end{spacing}` on the other hand *is* defined as a real environment and `\end{spacing}` does `\restore@spacing`, which amongst other things does `\par` to end a paragraph and adjusts the following spacing.

Comment: I just realised that there is an environment version of `\doublespacing`: It's `\begin{doublespace}...\end{doublespace}`. Again, that environment definition ends with `\restore@spacing` resetting the spacing after the environment in the same way `\begin{spacing}{2.0}...\end{spacing}` does it.

Comment: Thanks. ```\begin{doublespacing}``` only affects FIRST even with ```\end{doublespacing}``` relocated after THIRD. I think either ```\begin{spacing}{2.0}``` or ```\begin{doublespace}``` is safer.

Comment: If you extend your FIRST, SECOND and THIRD into multi-line paragraphs you will see that things are a bit more nuanced, but still the upshot is that you probably want to use the environment `spacing` or `doublespace` and not the command `\doublespacing` in environment form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a 10pt (default) font size, the `setspace` package sets the following stretch factors for `\onehalfspacing` and `\doublespacing`: 1.25 and 1.667. I guess the rationale for this is that for many common fonts -- including Computer Modern and Times Roman -- the baselinestretch is 1.2 times the nominal font size. Sure enough, `1.25 * 1.2=1.5` -- 50% more than the nominal font size -- and `1.667 * 1.2=2.0` = *twice* the nominal font size.

If, in contrast, you run `\begin{spacing}{2.0}` or, equivalently, `\setstretch{2.0}`, you get even wider spacing -- by a factor of 1.2 -- than "doublespacing".

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up comment: I'm not sure I understand the comment completely, but I believe it asserts that using the `spacing` environment (provided by the `setspace` package) with a factor of 1.667 produces line spacing that's different from using the command `\setstretch{1.667}`.

Please consider the following test program, which twice typesets a paragraph of filler text (produced via `\lipsum[3]`) in a two-column document. The left-hand column uses the environment `\begin{spacing}{1.667} ... \end{spacing}`, whereas the right-hand column uses the command `\setstretch{1.667}`. Sure enough, the line spacing in both paragraphs is the same.

The outcome is the same if one (a) replaces `\begin{spacing}{1.667}` with `\doublespacing` and (b) omits the instruction `\end{spacing}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{setspace,multicol,lipsum} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{multicols}{2} 

% Left-hand column:
\begin{spacing}{1.667} 
\lipsum[3] 
\end{spacing} 

% Right-hand column:
\setstretch{1.667} 
\lipsum[3] 

\end{multicols} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Then, altering ```2.0``` by ```1.667``` must equalize the two, but they are still different. Why?

Comment: @JunyongKim - Please see the addendum I posted to my answer.

Comment: As I understand the question it is more about the presence or absence of space after the `SECOND` in the two MWEs in the question and not primarily about the different spacing between `FIRST` and `SECOND`. (That's also how I read the OP's comment. As your answer rightly points out `\doublespacing` is actually `\setstretch{1.667}`. So if the two constructions from the question were the same, changing `\begin{spacing}{2.0}` to `\begin{spacing}{1.667}` should result in the same output, yet the space after `SECOND` is only present in the second MWE.)

Comment: @moewe - As I wrote in the addendum, I am *not* sure I understood the gist of the OP's follow-up comment correctly. (It's possible I didn't understand the initial query correctly either...) Maybe the OP will weigh in and clarify the overall typesetting objective.

Comment: I don't know if you looked at the compiled output of the two MWEs side-by-side, but aside from the small-ish difference in line spacing you explained (which I could only tell when I put the output side-by-side) there is a much more prominent difference in the spacing after *SECOND*, which is probably why the OP writes '`\begin{doublespacing}` only affects FIRST' and '`\begin{spacing}{2.0}` affects both FIRST and SECOND'. I take it that that difference was the main idea behind the question.

Comment: @moewe - I must confess that I didn't take the OP's FIRST and SECOND material to be representative of a real use case. My bad.

Comment: I guess the question would have looked slightly different if the 'FIRST' and 'SECOND' had been actual, multi-line paragraphs, because then the question would have presumably asked about the space *after* the environments and not about the environments not affecting 'SECOND'.

Comment: Though I was focusing on the space between SECOND and THIRD, I also learned the way ```\begin{spacing}``` works in detail. My apologies, and much appreciate all.